# Java: Disabling an Action should disable JButtons and JMenuItems

Tags: java, action, jbutton, jmenuitem

I'm writing a fairly simple IDE for developing embedded programs (for iRobot's Create platform) and almost every single button and menu item is backed by Java's Action system.
This has made it easier to handle all the operations that the user will want without duplicating an operation's trigger.

What I would like to know is, how do I disable the JButtons and JMenuItems created from an Action by disabling the Action itself?

In case it helps, I've written an Action-wrapping class that allows me to easily create a JButton or JMenuItem straight from the Action itself, which means I have hooks in place already to add stuff to the buttons or menu items should the need arise.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what happened when you tried to disable the action? As one of the answers mentions, should work without any further requiring any special wiring on your part. If it doesn't, something's wrong with your code :-)

Comment: @kleopatra: It seems it really is my code at fault here. I'm checking a JTabbedPane to see who's selected and somehow it's failing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:
   `anAction.setEnabled( false );`

Shorter answer:
http://sscce.org/

Comment: Okay, it seems my problem was not related to Actions not disabling the associated buttons and menu items, but more the code that should have been triggering the disabling of the Actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all buttons and menuitems to `List<AbstractButton> buttons` and add listener to action:

```
action.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
   public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
      if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("enabled")) {
         boolean isEnabled = (Boolean)evt.getNewValue();
         for (AbstractButton button : buttons) {
            button.setEnabled(isEnabled);
         }
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: It seems that my code is at fault more than Actions not disabling other things. I'll work through my code to see what the problem is.